# Show Dialog Fragment in Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How show MvxDialogFragment in MvxFragment. Can not use FragmentMaganer and other solution.

No Work

```
public void ShowFragmentLatestInvoices()
    {

        var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        var Manager = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        LatestInvoicesFragment LatestInvoicesFragment = new LatestInvoicesFragment();
        LatestInvoicesFragment.DataContext = ViewModel.InvoiceVM;
        LatestInvoicesFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "LatestInvoices_fragment");


        OnAttachFragment (LatestInvoices);
    }
```

Comment: why are you doing `OnAttachFragment (LatestInvoices);` this ?

Comment: Problem is SupportFragmentManager how include ? in line LatestInvoicesFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "LatestInvoices_fragment");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `private MvxFragmentActivity myContext;`

add `myContext = (MvxFragmentActivity)this.Activity;`

and replace `SupportFragmentManager` with `myContext.SupportFragmentMannager`

```
var FragmentTransactions = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
            var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            var Manager = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
            LatestInvoicesFragment LatestInvoicesFragment = new LatestInvoicesFragment();
            LatestInvoicesFragment.Show(myContext.SupportFragmentManager, "LatestInvoices_fragment");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get to `Activity` from the fragment by `getActivity()`, so you can do
`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` from your fragment

Comment: yes, but in xamarin I must use context, my correct solution I post

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it's xamarin